# How can I share a custom view with two VS Code extensions?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have two VS Code extensions I'm developing. Both interact with serial ports. I have created a custom explorer view in package.json for each extension to list the serial ports it detects.

```
"contributes": {
  "views": {
    "explorer": [
      {
        "id": "serialPortView",
        "name": "Serial Ports",
        "visibility": "visible",
        "when": "view.serialPortView.visible == false"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I then add the detected serial ports with a TreeDataProvider.

```
vscode.window.registerTreeDataProvider('serialPortView', serialPortDataProvider);
```

In package.json, commands are contributed to context menus for the view's child objects. This lets the user right-click on a serial port name in the view and run a command on the device attached to that port.

Here's a sample:

```
"contributes": {
  "menus": {
    "view/item/context": [
      {
        "command": "esptool.chip_id",
        "group": "5_esptoolGroup@1",
        "when": "view == serialPortView"
      },
      {
        "command": "esptool.flash_id",
        "group": "5_esptoolGroup@2",
        "when": "view == serialPortView"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Everything works fine when only one of the two extensions is enabled. But, when they're both enabled, I get an error message: *Cannot register multiple views with same id 'serialPortView'*

My initial thought was to use the when clause I've shown in my package.json snippet at the top. `"when": "view.serialPortView.visible == false"` My thinking is if the view is visible, the other extension has already registered it. If the view is not visible, this etension should register it. But, the error persists.

Is there a better way to conditionally register the view or to share the view between two extensions?